# Numdisplay download

Tags: python

I am first year Physics undergrad. I am trying to follow a tutorial on simulations using Python. However, a requirement is the download of Numdisplay package. As I am a new user of Ubuntu, I was wondering if you could provide me with the exact commands to write in the terminal to obtain the download.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I asume that you are using an **Ubuntu OS**. Second, you must to have **Python 2.2** or latter installed. If you don't have it, you can install it from [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) with this command: `sudo apt-get install python`.

Now, **Numdisplay** requires the use of **NumPy**. NumPy should have been installed with `stsci_python`, but if not, can be downloaded from the [NumPy development site](http://www.numpy.org/) (you have in the link all the informations that you need to download and install NumPy).

And now, you can install **Numdisplay**:

- [Download Numdisplay](http://stsdas.stsci.edu/numdisplay/download/numdisplay-1.5.6.tar.gz)
- Unpack the packet that you downloaded it, let's say in `~/numdisplay`
- To install Numdisplay execute the following commands in a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal):

  `cd ~/numdisplay`

  `python setup.py install --install-lib=<install-dir> --install-data=<install-dir>/numdisplay`

  `setenv PYTHONPATH <install-dir>`

  where `<install-dir>` is the directory where you want to install Numdisplay.

Sources: [Numdisplay Home Page](http://stsdas.stsci.edu/numdisplay/).

Other useful resources:

- http://stsdas.stsci.edu/numdisplay/doc/numdisplay_help.html
- http://www.stsci.edu/institute/software_hardware/pyraf/Installation
- http://www.researchpipeline.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=Numdisplay

Answer (score 1):

`numdisplay` has been merged into a larger library of tools. It is also added to PyPi which makes it very easy to install.

Make sure you have the dependencies installed:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-pip python-numpy
```

`distribute` is needed as well:

```
curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
python distribute_setup.py
```

Now install the wanted package with pip:

```
sudo pip install d2to1
sudo pip install stscipython
```

http://www.stsci.edu/institute/software_hardware/pyraf/stsci_python

http://www.stsci.edu/institute/software_hardware/pyraf/stsci_python/installation